# Enumeration types in Django

Tags: python, django, enumeration

I am trying to use enumeration types in Django but fell like I am not doing the right thing...

I am building an ebay-like webapp where my Listings are saved in the database with a `.category` attribute.

```
class Listing(models.Model):

    class Category(models.TextChoices):
        TOY = "TO", _("Toys")
        FASHION = "FA", _("Fashion")
        ELECTRONICS = "EL", _("Electronics")
        HOME = "HO", _("Home")
        OTHERS = "OT", _("Others")

    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=Category.choices,
        default=Category.OTHERS,
    )
```

I referred to [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-type) for the use of **Enumeration types** but there are some grey areas, as far as my understanding goes.

When I render a template to display a `Listing`, how do I pass the string value associated with the `.category` of my `Listing`?

I tried something like this:

```
return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
            "listing": listing,
            "category": Listing.Category[listing.category].label,
        })
```

Or can I access it through the `"listing"` variable? What I would like is for the browser to display `Home` for a `listing` with `listing.category = "HO"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use a field having choices, Django makes a method for you to use `get_<field_name>_display`, you can use it in your template like:

```
{{ listing.get_category_display }}
```

Comment: Nice! And is there a way to go the other way around? Say I have the string `"Home"` and want a list of all the listings with `listing.category="HO"`. Something like the following:
`listings = Listing.objects.filter(category=category_name.reverse("Home"))`

Comment: Don't think so as in most use cases you want to get the display value while the field stores the actual value. The most simple way of making such filters is `category=Listing.Category.HOME` as you would already have imported Listing anyway also this reduces chances of typos, etc.

Comment: The above would be `category=Listing.Category.HOME.value` in your case as you have used enumeration